# Generating (forcing) confidence percentages in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

I have a dependent variable (my 'label' in RapidMiner terms), that is a binary classification expressed as 'WIN' or 'NOTWIN'.

I know 'NOTWIN' is exhibited in about 90% of all observations.

When I try to run a K Nearest Neighbors approach, the generated results do not show a confidence percentage.  I think this has got to do with the fact that 'NOTWIN' is overwhelmingly the correct classification.

Nevertheless, what is important to me is the confidence percentage assigned to 'NOTWIN' (however large it may be), so as to gain an understanding of observations that fall into the 'WIN' classification.

How do I 'force' RapidMiner to show me a confidence percentage given this scenario?

Comment: welcome to our site :). While rapidminer questions are in general _on topic_, you might be better off asking the question on forum.rapid-i.com (the official forum), since the rm expertise is not extraordinarily high here ;). If you are going to ask the question there, please tell it by dropping a comment.